# How to use inheritance classes to create a fast food menu

Tags: class, inheritance

I need to create a fast food menu using inheritance in python but I am not sure how to get it to work using inheritance.
I can do it without the use of inheritance but it makes for very long and messy code.
Here is an example of what I have done for the code that needs executed. I'm not sure how to include this into a child class though.

```
    menu_list =[{"id": 1, "name":"1. Burger", "P":"£","Price":5 }, {"id": 2, "name":"2. Side", "P":"from £","Price":3 },
   {"id": 3, "name":"3. Drinks", "P":"from £","Price":2 },
   {"id": 4, "name":"4. Combo", "P":"from £","Price":8 }]
   print("The menu:")

   for o in menu_list:
    print(o.get("name"), o.get("P"),o.get("Price"))

if r == "1" or r == "burger":
    print("You have selected option 1: Burger")
    print("Please select what toppings you would like on your burger:")
    top = ["1. Lettuce", "2. Cheese", "3. Bacon", "4. All"]
    print(", ".join(top))
    u_condement = input("")
    p = u_condement.lower()
    if p == "all" or p == "4":
         print("You have selected all the toppings.")
         Order.append("Burger (All toppings): £5")
         print("Would like to choose anything else from the menu? (Y / N): ")
         a = input("")
         if a == "Y":
               print("")
         else:
            break
```

How would I use this code

Comment: Could you, please, add a language tag to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a parent class `FastFood` as follows:

```
class FastFood:
    def __init__(self, id, name, currency, price):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.currency = currency
        self.price = price
```

The fastfood items in the menu can be the children of this class with extra attributes. For example:

```
class Burger(FastFood):
    def __init__(self, toppings):
        super().__init__(1, "Burger", "£", 5)
        self.toppings = toppings

    def to_string(self):
        print(str(self.id) + ". " + self.name + ": (Toppings -" + self.toppings + ") ----> " + str(self.price) + self.currency)
```

The class `Burger` has an extra attribute named `toppings` that belongs to specifically to this class. It also inherits other attributes from it's parent class.

So, define more child classes like this as you need and add required child class specific attributes to those classes.

You just need to initialize this for burger:

```
burger = Burger("All")
```

Now call the `to_string()` defined in the `Burger` class and see what happens after this initialization:

```
burger.to_string()
```

this prints:

```
1. Burger: (Toppings -All) ----> 5£
```

You can also create other item objects defining their class and corresponding attributes:

```
class Side(FastFood):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(2, "Side", "£", 3)

    def to_string(self):
        print(str(self.id) + ". " + self.name + ": " + str(self.price) + self.currency)
    
    
class Drinks(FastFood):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(3, "Drinks", "£", 2)

    def to_string(self):
        print(str(self.id) + ". " + self.name + ": " + str(self.price) + self.currency)
```

**Study more about how inheritance in python works from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp)**

**EDIT**

As per your query in the comment of this answer, I'm adding a bit more thing to this answer showing what you've wanted.

To create a combo class, which will have the list of multiple fast food type objects, you can keep a list in that combo class and pass that to the constructor. Here the `food_list` parameter refers to the list of `FastFood` objects:

```
class Combo (FastFood):
    def __init__(self, food_list):
        super().__init__(4, "Combo", "£", 8)
        self.food_list = food_list
    
    def to_string(self):
        print(str(self.id) + ". " + self.name + ": " + str(self.price) + self.currency)
        print("Items in combo:")
        seq = 1
        for item in self.food_list:
            print (str(seq) + ". " + item.name)
            seq+=1
```

Now create objects for each type:

```
burger = Burger("All")
side = Side()
drinks = Drinks()
```

Add them to a list:

```
list_of_foods = [burger, side, drinks]
```

Create a combo object and pass the list to the constructor:

```
combo = Combo(list_of_foods)
```

To see the result call the `to_string()` function:

```
combo.to_string()
```

Comment: Thank you! Another question is that I am required to create a combo child class (i.e a meal that includes a burger, side and a drink). How would you call the other child classes to be used in the combo child class?

Comment: @Aidan, I've updated my answer according to your query. Please check now.